# what does " get caught up with somebody." mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTY4OSZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTY4OSZlZD0yMDE0LTEyLTMwVDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4

***I get really caught up with the people I write about.***

What does " get caught up with somebody." mean? What is the meaning of the above context?

Comment: Probably something like this: I get really *[caught up in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/caught+up+with)* the stories of the people I write about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *catch up with X* means to be up to date with X, either by getting information or performing outstanding tasks.

*Caught up* by itself can mean "stuck due to some circumstance outside of my control"  Interestingly *catch up* in present/future tense doesn't ever mean this, but *(will) get caught up by* can be used as an equivalent.  *Got caught up* is valid as well.

*With X* can be used with this sense of *caught up* which works well if X is a group of people and you temporarily joined or "got caught in" their group for a while unintentionally.

So this second meaning is likely intended.